# Problema al enviar un email desde código por SMPT office365

Tags: c#, asp.net

estoy intentando enviar un email desde una aplicación y no hay manera.
El código es este:

```
public void SendEmail()
{
   MailMessage oMail = new MailMessage();
   oMail.From = new MailAddress("direccion@dominio.com");
   oMail.To.Add("destinatario@email.es");
   oMail.Subject = "Prueba";
   oMail.Body = "Prueba email";
   oMail.IsBodyHtml = true;
   oMail.Priority = MailPriority.Normal;

   SmtpClient oSMTPServer = new SmtpClient();
   oSMTPServer.Host = "smtp.office365.com";
   oSMTPServer.Port = 587;
   oSMTPServer.Credentials = new System.Net.NetworkCredential("direccion@dominio.com", "contraseña");
   oSMTPServer.EnableSsl = true;
   oSMTPServer.DeliveryMethod = SmtpDeliveryMethod.Network;
   oSMTPServer.UseDefaultCredentials = true;
   oSMTPServer.Send(oMail);
}
```

El error que obtengo es este:

> El servidor SMTP requiere una conexión segura o el cliente no se
>   autenticó. La respuesta del servidor fue: 5.7.57 SMTP; Client was not
>   authenticated to send anonymous mail during MAIL FROM
>   [xxxx999xx9999.xxx999.PROD.OUTLOOK.COM]

He probado con el puerto 25 y el puerto 587 y he realizado todas las combinaciones posibles con las propiedades: EnableSssl y UseDefaultCredentials.

¿Es posible enviar emails a través de office365 con la clase SmtpClient?

Comment: Una duda, has activado la configuración POP del correo que pones en From? Si no te da problemas el UseDefaultCredentials = true, entonces verifica que en tu correo Outlook no te bloqueé la salida de correos desde aplicaciones externas. Saludos

Answer (score 1):

El problema está en que defines las credenciales por defecto luego de haberlas definido, intenta con el siguiente código:

```
public void SendEmail()
{
   MailMessage oMail = new MailMessage();
   oMail.From = new MailAddress("direccion@dominio.com");
   oMail.To.Add("destinatario@email.es");
   oMail.Subject = "Prueba";
   oMail.Body = "Prueba email";
   oMail.IsBodyHtml = true;
   oMail.Priority = MailPriority.Normal;

   SmtpClient oSMTPServer = new SmtpClient("domain-com.mail.protection.outlook.com");
   oSMTPServer.Port = 587;
   oSMTPServer.Credentials = new System.Net.NetworkCredential("direccion@dominio.com", "contraseña","domain.com");
   oSMTPServer.EnableSsl = true;
   oSMTPServer.Send(oMail);
}
```

### Actualización

El problema va por el lado de configuración del dominio, utiliza el `MX endpoint` de tu Office 365 tenant, el nombre que completo que termina en "`mail.protection.outlook.com.`"

Si se ha configurado los records txt del DNS, verifica que sea similar a este: **v=spf1 [static IP address] include: spf.protection.outlook.com ~all**, donde " **[static IP address]**" es opcional.

Comment: fredyfx, obtengo el mismo error al desactivar esas dos líneas que comentas.

Comment: respuesta actualizada

Answer (score 1):

En mi caso, sólo tuve que habilitar la autenticación por SMTP para el correo que realiza el envío.

https://docs.microsoft.com/es-es/exchange/clients-and-mobile-in-exchange-online/authenticated-client-smtp-submission

La solución la encontré utilizando la librería MailKit, pero, una vez habilitada la autenticación SMTP, puede volver a usar la forma antigua que es como la que muestras en tu código exceptuando esto:

```
//oSMTPServer.DeliveryMethod = SmtpDeliveryMethod.Network; 
oSMTPServer.UseDefaultCredentials =false;
```

Un saludo.